# Не могу переключится на ветку

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Не могу переключится на ветку в Android Studio.
Пытаюсь через VCS сделать commit and push(+pull сделал), выдаёт нечто подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или если при переходе под студией в VCS -> Git -> Branches you will see this screen
Пробую перейти на ветку Vadim, нету команды checkout, хотя должна быть по идее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

git status показывает следующее

```
    Sashas-iMac:999_app_android vadim$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .DS_Store
        .gradle/
        .idea/
        999.iml
        999_app_android.iml
        _999/.DS_Store
        _999/gradle/.DS_Store
        _999/libs/.DS_Store
        _999/src/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/activities/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/adapter/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/adapter/formAddAds/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/fragments/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/rest/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/java/md/simpals/md999/views/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/drawable/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/layout-large/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/layout/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/values-ro/.DS_Store
        _999/src/main/res/values/.DS_Store
        build.gradle
        build/
        gradle/
        gradlew
        gradlew.bat
        local.properties
        settings.gradle

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Примечание: Данный проект устанавливал с архива.

Comment: найдите файл, который описан в ошибке, и удалите его, как сказано в ошибке

Comment: Что говорит `git status`?

Comment: @metalurgus файл удалил, но при очередной попытке пуша, выдаёт ошибку "Push rejected", Push to Vadim/master was rejected.

Comment: И дальше должна быть причина реджекта. Или просто надо сначала пул сделать

Comment: @metalurgus откорректировал вопрос, проблема не решилась.

Comment: Что произошло, когда вы сделали пул?

Comment: @metalurgus на скрине написано: Pull failed, после чего выдал дилоговое окно с 5-ю файлами.

Comment: Добавьте неотслеживаемые файлы в .gitingnore, либо добавьте их в отслеживаемые и закомитье, либо спрячьте их через stash.

Comment: @AlexChermenin имеете в виду эти 5 файлов которые предложила AS удалить?

Comment: Полный список неотслеживаемых файлов в выводе команды `git status`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас же там написано: Pull failed. Пулл не получился, потому что он предполагает изменения в файлах, которые у вас тоже были изменены. Непонятно, что должно стать с изменениями после пулла. Даже список дан из пяти файлов, блокирующих пулл.

Push не получается потому, что ваша история ветки `master` расходится с историей ветки `master` на удалённом сервере, т.е. `origin/master`.

> Не могу переключится на ветку в Android Studio

Ни одно из действий, которые вы описали, не должно приводить к переключению на ветку. Что происходит при `git checkout Vadim`?

Если переключаетесь, то проблема вроде бы решена и можно коммитить туда.

Если нет, значит внесённые изменения конфликтуют с этой веткой. Что можно сделать для починки:

1. Для начала, завести файл .gitignore и добавить в него всякий хлам вроде `.DS_Store`
2. Создать новую ветку: `git branch backup`
3. Сохранить все нужные изменения в коммит. По крайней мере те, которые конфликтуют.
4. Переключиться на `master`. Подтянуть изменения с удалённого сервера.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git fetch
   ```
5. Теперь надо определиться, а можно ли вам вообще коммитить прямо в `master`? **Если да**, то попробуйте сделать так:

   ```
   git pull --rebase
   ```

   При этом коммиты из ветки `remote/master` подтянутся в неизменном виде и порядке в вашу ветку, а ваши собственные коммиты встанут после них.

   Если нет, то надо вернуть `master` к тому состоянию, которое на удалённом сервере.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git reset --hard origin/master
   ```
6. Теперь у вас:

   - В ветке `master` то, что и у всех
   - Все изменения забэкаплены
   - Можно переключиться на вашу ветку.

Comment: И какие действия? удалить эти 5 файлов чтоли?..

Пробовал создавать новую ветку, тоже не получается.

Comment: @VadimMorozov дополнил ответ

Comment: @VadimMorozov как именно вы пробовали создать новую ветку, что у вас это не получилось?

Comment: ветку получилось создать/удалить, сейчас попробую вышеперечисленные шаги.
git checkout Vadim не работает - опять эти 5 файлов всплывают.

Comment: git reset --hard origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: @VadimMorozov это я предполагал, что у вас `remote` имеет имя `origin`, следовательно имя ветки будет `origin/master`. Раз такой ветки нет, значит удаленный сервер называется иначе. Что показывает `git remote -v`?